# Unknown space left by nav-menu in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this weird gap in the middle of my work in HTML. 
[image: You can see what I am talking about here...]

The space being occupied matches the menu space, so I guess that what is causing but I don't know how to resolve it. But I used `transform-Y()` to send the menu up by 150%, so it won't show on the screen until a button is clicked. However, when the menu disappears, that large white gap is left behind.

Hear is the html:

```
<!-- Header -->
    <header class="header">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="header-child nav-menu">
                <div class="nav-bar"></div>
                <div class="nav-bar"></div>
                <div class="nav-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-child logo">
                Xpresschow
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu-container">
                <div class="menu-item">Home</div>
                <div class="menu-item">About</div>
                <div class="menu-item">Faq</div>
                <div class="menu-item sign-in">Sign In</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Header -->
```

css:

```
.menu {
    background: var(--primaryDark);
    color: var(--primaryLight);
    transform: translateY(-150%);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

.menu-container {
    height: 300px;
    padding: 1rem;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.show {
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.menu-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Header CSS:

```
header {
    background: var(--primaryLight);
    min-height: 4%;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    transition: all ease 1s;
}

.head {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/q3ymfnx9/1/) is a fiddle.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I don't think the issue is from my `justify-content`, I make this claim simply because I have already toggled it in an attempt to solve this problem. I have, however, included my header CSS. So as to shed more light on the issue.

Comment: I have added a fiddle.

Comment: Yup yup yup... working. I guess it was the height and padding properties that left the remnant. Do you want to put an answer up so I can accept it? Also, for future references for learners like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of `.header { min-height: 4%}` and `.menu { transform: translateY(-150%); }` causes the problem. The browser does not know 150% of what height as `.menu` has no specific height.

Counting spacing and box-shadow you should at least move `.menu` 390px up to get it out of the way

- remove `.header { min-height: 4%; }`
- set `.menu { transform: translateY(-390px); height: 0; }` to move up and hide content
- set `.show { transform: translateY(0); height: auto; }` and you're done

modify / toggle `<div class="menu show">` to see the effect....

The code:

```css
:root {
    --primaryColor: #19323C;
    --secondaryColor: rgb(255, 139, 162);
    --primaryDark: #19323C;
    --primaryLight: #fff;
    --accent: #8C5E58;
}


.header {
    background: var(--primaryLight);
/*    min-height: 4%;  REMOVE */
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    transition: all ease 1s;
}

.head {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%
}

.nav-menu {
    max-width: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-bar {
    width: 45px;
    height: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: var(--primaryColor);
}

.logo {
    font-family: var(--logoFont);
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: var(--primaryColor);
}

.menu {
    background: var(--primaryDark);
    color: var(--primaryLight);
    transform: translateY(-390px); /* MODIFY */
    height: 0; /* ADD */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

.menu-container {
    height: 300px;
    padding: 1rem;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.show {
    transform: translateY(0);
    height: auto; /* ADD */
}

.menu-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
[outlines="1"] * { outline: 2px dashed purple }
```

```html
<body outlines="0">
<header class="header">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="header-child nav-menu">
      <div class="nav-bar"></div>
      <div class="nav-bar"></div>
      <div class="nav-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-child logo">
      Xpresschow
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-container">
      <div class="menu-item">Home</div>
      <div class="menu-item">About</div>
      <div class="menu-item">Faq</div>
      <div class="menu-item sign-in">Sign In</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

</body>
```